# Pandas : Sum multiple columns and get results in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a "sample.txt" like this.

```
idx A   B   C   D   cat
J   1   2   3   1   x
K   4   5   6   2   x
L   7   8   9   3   y
M   1   2   3   4   y
N   4   5   6   5   z
O   7   8   9   6   z
```

With this dataset, I want to get sum in row and column.
In row, it is not a big deal. 
I made result like this.

```
### MY CODE ###
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt',sep="\t",index_col='idx')
df.info()

df2 = df.groupby('cat').sum()
print( df2 )
```

The result is like this.

```
      A   B   C   D
cat                
x     5   7   9   3
y     8  10  12   7
z    11  13  15  11
```

But I don't know how to write a code to get result like this.
(simply add values in column A and B as well as column C and D)

```
    AB  CD
J   3   4
K   9   8
L   15  12
M   3   7
N   9   11
O   15  15
```

Could anybody help how to write a code?

By the way, I don't want to do like this.
(it looks too dull, but if it is the only way, I'll deem it)

```
df2 = df['A'] + df['B']
df3 = df['C'] + df['D']
df = pd.DataFrame([df2,df3],index=['AB','CD']).transpose()
print( df )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pass a dictionary or callable to `groupby` it gets applied to an axis. I specified axis one which is columns.

```
d = dict(A='AB', B='AB', C='CD', D='CD')
df.groupby(d, axis=1).sum()
```

Comment: Well this is new for me

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Your answer is what I was looking for few hours.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with `sum`:

```
df = df.set_index('idx')
df = pd.concat([df[['A', 'B']].sum(1), df[['C', 'D']].sum(1)], axis=1, keys=['AB','CD'])
print( df)
     AB  CD
idx        
J     3   4
K     9   8
L    15  12
M     3   7
N     9  11
O    15  15
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I think `pir` solution is much better, so use it ;)

Comment: But sometimes, I need to sum 'A' and 'B' and 'C'.
Sometimes sum 'B' and 'C' and 'D'.
Which columns and how many columns are variable.

Comment: In your case, I have to keep 'A' and 'B' fixed.

Comment: Yes, and piRSquared's was what I was looking for. But please allow me to say thank you to your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you need? By using axis=1 with DataFrame.apply, you can use the data that you want in a row to construct a new column. Then you can drop the columns that you don't want anymore.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], data=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
1  1  2  3  4

In [7]: df['CD'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['C'] + x['D'], axis=1)

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   A  B  C  D  CD
0  1  2  3  4   7
1  1  2  3  4   7

In [13]: df.drop(['C', 'D'], axis=1)
Out[13]:
   A  B  CD
0  1  2   7
1  1  2   7
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Though I take piRSquared's answer, I want to say thank you to you.