# How to find the difference between multiple columns of a given data frame and save the result as a separate data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have data frame as below ,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,7,1,4,7],'B':[2,5,8,2,5,8],'C':[3,6,9,3,6,9],'D':[1,2,3,1,2,3]})
    A   B   C   D
0   1   2   3   1
1   4   5   6   2
2   7   8   9   3
3   1   2   3   1
4   4   5   6   2
5   7   8   9   3
```

how can I find the difference between column (A & B) and save as AB, and do the same with (C & D) and save as CD within the data frame.

Expected output:

```
    AB   CD
0   1.0 -2.0
1   1.0 -4.0
2   1.0 -6.0
3   1.0 -2.0
4   1.0 -4.0
5   1.0 -6.0
```

tried using

```
d = dict(A='AB', B='AB', C='CD', D='CD')
df.groupby(d, axis=1).diff()
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891001/pandas-sum-multiple-columns-and-get-results-in-multiple-columns?rq=1), this works well for `sum()`, but does not work as expected for `diff()`. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: This post should help 
 https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46434/dataframe-columns-difference-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference is `diff` not aggregate values like `sum`, but return new 2 columns - first filled by `NAN` and second with values.

So possible solution here is remove only `NaN`s columns by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
d = dict(A='AB', B='AB', C='CD', D='CD')
df1 = df.rename(columns=d).groupby(level=0, axis=1).diff().dropna(axis=1, how='all')
print (df1)
    AB   CD
0  1.0 -2.0
1  1.0 -4.0
2  1.0 -6.0
3  1.0 -2.0
4  1.0 -4.0
5  1.0 -6.0
```

Comment: thanks for explaining. what is the use here of assigning `A` and `B` to the same variable name `AB`?

Comment: @Shijith - simpliest is rename columns by dict and then use `level=0 and axis=1` parameters - answer was edited.

Comment: ,thank you. yes have to rename first and then group